# Splitting Access Databases

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an access database that I have been using for a while. I have been meaning to split the database for a while but hesitant to. I have many forms that link to tables. VBA code that aid in the forms and creating reports from this access database. Sometimes the VBA code will have a dynamic query that changes on certain conditions and runs a DoCmd.RunSQL.

If I split the database will all my VBA code break down as it points to the tables within my database. Do they need to be pointed to the backend or pointing towards the linked table is enough. Will the split handle this by itself?

Let me know If I was clear enough. My main concern is my forms/VBA code will stop working.

Comment: Your code should be moved to the front end. Just make a back up copy and try it :)

Comment: Stop worrying and give it a try. It's a non issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a backup, go to meny Database Tools, locate the Split database wizard.

Run this, and you are done.